# Hadoop - Maintaining the replication factor after failure and recovery

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Say a data node goes down. The replication factor has been configured to be 2.
Would the namenode try to maintain the replication factor, and copy over the lost data blocks over to another machine?

In case the above is true, then say the same data node comes back online. Would the namenode then delete the extra data blocks, because now the replication factor would be 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, namenode will try to maintain the replication factor.

Over-replicated blocks will be randomly removed from the nodes. See this [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#If_I_add_new_DataNodes_to_the_cluster_will_HDFS_move_the_blocks_to_the_newly_added_nodes_in_order_to_balance_disk_space_utilization_between_the_nodes.3F)